# Passing parent component to all child components in blazor via rendertree

Tags: forms, parameters, components, blazor

I created an custom form component in blazor and inherited from the default EditForm component to add some functionality.

```
public class CustomForm : EditForm
```

I want to pass the instance of the form component to all its children, so a child can retrieve it via a cascading parameter like so

```
[CascadingParameter]
public CustomForm Form { get; set; }
```

I took over the BuildRenderTree Method of the default Editform

```
   protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        Debug.Assert(EditContext != null);

        // If _editContext changes, tear down and recreate all descendants.
        // This is so we can safely use the IsFixed optimization on CascadingValue,
        // optimizing for the common case where _editContext never changes.
        builder.OpenRegion(EditContext.GetHashCode());

        builder.OpenElement(0, "form");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "onsubmit", _handleSubmitDelegate);
        builder.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<EditContext>>(3);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "IsFixed", true);
        builder.AddAttribute(5, "Value", EditContext);
        builder.AddAttribute(6, "ChildContent", ChildContent?.Invoke(EditContext));
        builder.CloseComponent();
        builder.CloseElement();

        builder.CloseRegion();
    }
```

But i do not know how to manipulate this code to achieve my goal.

Comment: Do the children need an EditForm or a CustomForm?

Comment: CustomForm, since i want to access new props/methods that I added.

Comment: What does your custom form actually do?  What props/methods does it implement? 
 Can you show some example code to us?  I kind of suspect you're going in the wrong direction, but won't know until I see more code.

Comment: That might be the case,  since I'm still relatively new to blazor :)I don't have much code yet, but what I am generally trying to accomplish is the following:
I want to create a Custom Form component which exposes Events which child components can subscribe to. For example "Submit Requested" and "Submit Completed" events could be subscribed to by a SubmitButton component, which toggles its disabled state in the context to these events.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pass any object as cascading value so you can override the BuildRenderTree like this and the `CustomForm` instance will be passed to the child components. Explicit cast to `RenderFragment` is needed to create delegate of this type, otherwise `CascadingValue<>.SetParametersAsync` will throw an invalid cast exception.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;

namespace BlazorTest
{
    public class CustomForm : EditForm
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenRegion(0);            

            builder.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<CustomForm>>(1);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "Value", this);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)base.BuildRenderTree);
            builder.CloseComponent();

            builder.CloseRegion();
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this with these components:

CustomFormComponent.razor

```
<h3>CustomFormComponent</h3>

@code {
    private CustomForm _form;

    [CascadingParameter]
    public CustomForm Form 
    {
        get => _form;
        set
        {
            _form = value;
            Console.WriteLine("CustomForm set in CustomFormInput");
        }
    }
}
```

TestPage.razor

```
@page "/test"

<CustomForm Model=model>
    <CustomFormComponent />
</CustomForm>

@code {
    private AModel model = new();

    private class AModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I just want to add that I'm not an expert in this and I'm not sure if you should do it this way. Maybe it would be better to use EditForm as a child component of the CustomForm because you don't have to worry about BuildRenderTree method when using razor markup.

```
<CascadingValue Value=this>
    <EditForm Model=model>
        @ChildContent
    </EditForm
</CascadingValue>
```